# commit disappeared when using git rebase

Tags: git

First step

```
echo "1111111111" >> test.txt && git commit -m "1"
echo "2222222222" >> test.txt && git commit -m "2"
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Next change the configuration similar to the following

```
s hash 1
p hash 2
```

Then the git will tell you that you made a mistake

```
git rebase --edit-todo
//set the configuration similar to the following
//it's worth noting that 'p hash 2' doesn't show up
p hash 1
git rebase --continue
```

Finally, the second commit disappeared!

Is that normal? Is there any way to get the Git repository back to where it was before `git rebase -i HEAD~2` was executed?

Comment: I will leave a hint, how you can restore the branch to state before rebase. So basically the commit's are always there. So for example, run `git reflog`, and then find the hash of the commit:
`4a73261 HEAD@{}: rebase (start): checkout HEAD~2`
`d5f6458 HEAD@{}: commit: 2 <-- you are looking for that hash`
`e9497a3 (HEAD -> <branch>) HEAD@{}: commit: 1`
And then just force your branch to look at that commit:
`git branch <branch> -f <hash>`
You can of course as well create new branch, based on that commit.

Comment: @kadewu @matt
Thank you guys. `git reflog` is realy helpful.
It seems that `git rebase` does have this bug and I will report it to the official website

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug to me. When you say `git rebase --edit-todo`, you lose 2 because it doesn't show up in the second (edited) todo list, which is the same as asking to drop it — and so when you do the edit and continue the rebase from there, Git *does* drop it.

However, there is an easy solution: don't say `git rebase --edit-todo`. When Git stops you and offers to let you edit the todo list, just say `git rebase --abort` instead and start over, and this time, don't ask to squash the first item in the todo list, which (as you now know) is illegal.

If you already *did* the edit of the todo list and said `git rebase --continue`, so that the rebase is now over, you can easily undo everything by looking in the reflog (`git reflog`). Look for the first commit marked `rebase (start)` and `reset --hard` to the commit *before* that (that is, *after* it in the list). The one you want to reset to will probably say `commit: 2` (or whatever your real last commit message was) so you'll know you're doing the right thing.